# Odoo website image upload and validation for file type

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10, qweb, odoo-website

I checked the website_hr_recruitment module and found that there is provision for uploading the resume. But there is no sort of security restriction here, which I feel is a serious loophole as far as security is concerned. Anyway, I try to do the same with an image, and create an entry into one of my custom models which contain a binary field. The following is my code:

template.xml:

```
<div class="form-group form-field ">
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 text-right">
    <label class="control-label" for="image">Image</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-8">
    <input type="file" class="form-control o_website_form_input" name="image"/>
</div>

</div>
```

controller.py:

```
if post['image']:
    vals.update({'photo': post['image']})
```

But the image doesn't seem to be updated in the binary field 'photo'
Any help would be appreciated? And also if anyone from Odoo has opinions about the security issue, please comment regarding the same as well.

Thanks,
Yaseen Shareef

Comment: are you used website controller?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if post['image']:
    vals.update({'photo': post['image'].read().encode('base64')})
```

Comment: I did that in another way, the image is being set in the backend now. The next issue is validation at the frontend due to security issue. I need to check the image filetype on upload, and also size.

Comment: for file type use this: `<input type="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx" />`

Comment: That's not working on upload of the file. I need it as an onchange

Comment: Then write jquery to fetch file input and validate it.